# INSERT INTO from HTML form & INSERT FROM database TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

-- UPDATED --

I am trying to INSERT data from a HTML FORM and a database TABLE(1) INTO TABLE(2). The below code works partially. So far data from table1 does insert into table2, as well as incrementing (having the same user enter multiple form data). But the UPDATE data is not inserting. When I check the table values, after submitting the form, room_temp shows the same 1 of 3 options (even if I've not selected it) and stage1 - stage10 shows the value of 0, even if I've entered 1,2,3 etc....

```
           $sql = "
            INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, user_fname, user_lname, user_dob)
            SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname, user_dob FROM table1;

            UPDATE table2 SET 

            room_temp='$rtemp',
            stage1='$ustage1',
            stage2='$ustage2',
            stage3='$ustage3',
            stage4='$ustage4',
            stage5='$ustage5',
            stage6='$ustage6',
            stage7='$ustage7',
            stage8='$ustage8',
            stage9='$ustage9',
            stage10='$ustage10'

            WHERE test_id=1";
```

Please tell me how this query should be.

Form Code - examples of my 2 input fields

```
        <label id="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="roomTemp" value="warm" <?php if (isset($rtemp) && $rtemp=="warm") echo "checked";?>>&nbsp;Warm</label>
        <label id="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="roomTemp" value="cool" <?php if (isset($rtemp) && $rtemp=="cool") echo "checked";?>>&nbsp;Cool</label>
        <label id="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="roomTemp" value="cold" <?php if (isset($rtemp) && $rtemp=="cold") echo "checked";?>>&nbsp;Cold</label>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="rateLabel" for="0-3mins">Stage 1<br />5 / 8 (miles/km) ph</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_stage1" placeholder="HR after 0 - 3 mins" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $ustage1;}?>">
        </div>
```

Comment: _You_ need to tell _us_ how the query should be by either telling us what error you have or by telling us what desired outcome you want.

Comment: Currently - data from table1 inserts successfully into table2. But data from the HTML form doesn't insert into table2. For example - fields stage1 - stage10 has values of 0, even though I've submitted 40,50,60 etc through the form. There's a syntax error, and I don't know where

Answer (score -1):

What is the primary key of the table?
If it has one I.e userid then

Replace the second statement by an update statement

```
update table2 
set value1=...
from table1
where userid=1
```

Comment: The primary key is userID. But how do I avoid this error - 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'. Would making the userID 'not unique' work?

Comment: The second statement should be an update, else you get the duplicate key error, alternative you could also try to make a single insert. I.e. Insert into table1 (...) select userid,..., 'rtemp' from table2. That means you add the values from the second update as cnst. To the select. Try this select userid, 'hello world' from table2

Comment: Ok - I'm getting closer to where I want to be.